# Biztalk: Is there a way to generate class from schema or schema from class?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I want to accelerate creating of my BizTalk projects. I have schemas corresponds to classes in another project. Is there any tool/way to easily generate schemas from class files or vice verse, so I will have to create only schema and class will be generated automatically (or vice verse)?

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use the xsd.exe tool

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx

that way you can  generate a class or vice verse

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate classes from schema,You can use XSD.exe tool to generate the class. for more information please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this tool.

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

It is very helpful for me, hope it helps!